# Word describing the feeling of being there to experience something first hand

Tags: single-word-requests, philosophy

There's a word I learned in a philosophy lecture and a YouTube video a long time ago regarding the feeling of being there to experience a thing first-hand. For example, being at the Louvre to see the Mona Lisa with your own eyes in contrast to looking at a really detailed image from a computer screen. While the latter lets you zoom in every nook and cranny of the painting, there's a "feeling" on just being there physically in the presence of the Da Vinci painting.

Comment: Virtual reality, or déjà-vu?

Comment: No, those are different to what I'm describing. Deja-vu is a sense of familiarity to something that isn't familiar, and virtual reality is something about computer simulations.

Comment: I can think of a number of words. I'm not 100% sure what you are asking but how about a feeling of  *immersion* in the phenomenon?

Comment: There is a philosophy SE. It would help to know what the philosophy lecture was on. Walter Benjamin talked about the [aura](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/art-terms/a/aura) of an original artwork. There are also various philosophical terms such as Dinglichkeit and Haecceity which refer to the uniqueness of an object. But I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably thinking of ***existentialism***, which [Britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/topic/existentialism) describes in the following way:

> Existence is always a ***being-in-the-world***—i.e., in a concrete and historically determinate situation that limits or conditions choice. Humans are therefore called, in Martin Heidegger’s phrase, Dasein (“***there being***”) because ***they are defined by the fact that they exist, or are in the world and inhabit it***.

One concept existentialism deals with is ***situatedness***:

> Situatedness is the necessity of viewing or
> understanding life and existence from the ‘inside’. Human existence cannot be abstracted from its world because being-in-the-world is part of the ontological structure of that existence. ([Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/existent/))

Related to the meaning you are giving is the term ***empirical*** which means:

> Based on, concerned with, or verifiable by observation or experience ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/empirical.html))

Note that [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empiricism) defines empiricism as

> a theory that all knowledge originates in experience

Answer (score 0):

I'd use '[a sense of] **immediacy**'.

Oxford languages describe this:

> *immediacy* [noun]
>
> the quality of bringing one into direct and instant involvement with
> something, giving rise to a sense of urgency or excitement.
>
> - *email works because it has the immediacy of a scribbled memo*

and [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/immediacy):

> *immediacy* [noun] [non-count]
>
> the fact that something seems real and important, so that you feel
> involved with it:
>
> - *Pre-recorded TV programmes have so much less immediacy and warmth than live theatre.*

and another example, from the [Cambridge English Corpus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/sense-of-immediacy):

> - *A greater sense of immediacy would have been obtained generally had the workers been allowed to speak themselves instead of the authors
>   speaking on their behalf.*

Answer (score 0):

*Kairos* is an ancient Greek word meaning 'the right, critical, or opportune moment'. In modern Greek, kairos also means 'weather' or 'time'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kairos